# Is it possible to Continue / fine tune a previous operation?

Tags: extrude

Example: I want to extrude a face, I do it, then I rotate my object to give it a better look and realize I should have gone a bit lower or higher.
I could undo and do a new extrude, or I could star a new extrude and delete the previous face I guess.

However, in general, is there a way to continue a previous operation (let it be extrude, inset, bevel, whatever) ?

Comment: you can as long as you don't do a new action, go into the Operator Box (bottom left of the 3D view), or press F9

Comment: So as @moonboots mentioned you can bring up the tool options, in the case you described you could do that if you were rotating the view to see the object better. If you rotate the object itself with R for example, then the settings of the extrusion are gone.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you both!